# YII validator for multiple models at the same time

Tags: php, validation, yii

How can i have a validator that look at the same time to 2 models?

I have the following situation:
 An ActiveRecord foo and An ActiveRecord bar.

Whem an attribute of foo is X i want that the field A of bar be required, if it's Y i want that the field B of bar be required.

Comment: [Take a look at scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#scenario-detail). You can create rules for specific scenarios.

Comment: besides scenarios you can use additional variable in class (that is not defined as database column). `public $_x;` And use this variable to detect if use one scenario or another.